# How do I convert a varchar price column containing a currency symbol and then sum it?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, string-conversion

I have a table called `tbl_procie` which has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_procie` (
    `id` int,
    `price` varchar(25)
);
```

Data:

```
id  price
 1   $2.5
 2   $5.3
```

I want to be able to `SUM()` the price however it is currently a `varchar` column also containing currency symbols.  I should get the answer `7.8`.

Comment: price column is an int datatype in mysql ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store it in a different format, like
`[id price currency]`? Then numeric values wouldn't have characters in them?

Comment: This is not created by me its created by client and store data .So I want to know about issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(REPLACE(price,'$','')) AS cr 
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE Valet_Company = "Demo Company"
```

Comment: If the price column always has a $ sign my answer would be faster.

Comment: Thanks Great answer Vivek...(Y)

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT SUM(price) AS [Price Total] FROM tbl_temp`

Or if that doesnt remove the $ sign automatically try

`SELECT SUM(TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM price)) AS [Price Total] FROM tbl_temp`

Comment: This doens't work when there is a $-sign before each price (read the question).

Comment: Updated answer to tailor for both

Answer (score 2):

try below:

```
select sum(cast(price as double)) from tbl_temp
```